# Powershell script to get all the Read-Only columns inside a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell, read-only

I have 4 custom lists which i want to replicate manually inside another tenant. now i can access the list content type and re-create the columns, but how i can know if the list have any Read-Only fields which will be hidden inside the UI? can i run a power shell script to get all the hide fields inside a list?

Answer (score 0):

You care this:

```
cls

Import-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Verbose

$cred= Get-Credential

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/"
 
#Connect to PnP Online 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred 

$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "Contact" #List Name
$fields=Get-PnPField -list $list  

$fields.Count #count of all fields

$ReadOnlyfields = $fields | where {$_.ReadOnlyField -eq $True}

$ReadOnlyfields.Count #count of all ReadOnly Fields


#Print out all readonly fields
Foreach($fld in $fields)
{
    if($fld.ReadOnlyField -eq $True)
    {
      Write-Host $fld.Title `t $fld.InternalName `t $fld.Id

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@SharePoint TestDev,

If you want to replicate lists, why not have a try below methods:

- [Save list as template and export it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)

[image]

- [Use some 3rd party tool to migrate list to another tenant](https://sharegate.com/blog/copy-list-in-sharepoint-to-office365-tool#sharegate)